# Back and forth conversation in Watson conversation

Tags: watson-conversation

How can I achieve back and forth conversation in watson conversation service? In the image when the true node is reached the next node to traverse will be based on the input provided. If the second input is provided at the same level then the watson will go back to root node.

Let me know how to stay on same node and respond to differnt user input. Thanks.

[image: Watson Converstaion]

Answer (score 2):

What you described is how Conversation works. As you move down branches, it will attempt to match a node. If it does not find a matching node in a branch, it will return to the root to find the answer.

To prevent this your last node in the branch has to be a `true` condition and then either a message, and/or a continue from to return to the correct point in the branch.

I did a blog post on this a while back.

https://sodoherty.com/2016/09/10/understanding-how-a-conversation-flows/

Comment: Thanks Simon. I have one more question. How to handle irrelevant conversation in the middle of Dialog flow. As the conversation seems pretty much logical flow from root to child nodes.